# Dapperplus add round to bulkinsert

Tags: c#, dapper-plus

We switched from dapper to dapper plus for performance in bulk inserts.

Now I am converting all the existing queries but I found some functionality that I apparently cannot do with dapper plus (or I don't know how yet)

In my previous query I round the values inside the query, and I converted that to this:

```
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Model>().Table("Table").Identity("ID")
                .Map(x => x.Id, "ID")
                .Map(x => x.Timestamp, "Timestamp")
                .Map(x => x.Latitude, "GPS latitude")
                .Map(x => x.Longitude, "GPS longitude")
                .Map(x => x.Direction, "ROUND(Direction (°)::numeric, 1)")
                .Map(x => x.Speed, "ROUND(Speed (kph)::numeric, 1)")
                .Map(x => x.DeviceId, "DEVICE_ID");
```

But apparently rounding inside the column name is not really working. Is there another way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be possible to make the rounding in the database but this is easier to do it during the mapping.

```
DapperPlusManager.Entity<Model>().Table("Table").Identity("ID")
            .Map(x => x.Id, "ID")
            .Map(x => x.Timestamp, "Timestamp")
            .Map(x => x.Latitude, "GPS latitude")
            .Map(x => x.Longitude, "GPS longitude")
            .Map(x => Math.Round(x.Direction), "Direction")
            .Map(x => Math.Round(x.Speed), "Speed")
            .Map(x => x.DeviceId, "DEVICE_ID");
```

If you need to absolutely do it in the database, let me know and I will update my answer.